# How can i change size and position of button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, dimensions

i dont know how to properly change the size and position of a button in a panel how do i do it?

I used setSize for button1 didnt work
I used setBounds for size and position but didnt work

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppGUI fenster = new AppGUI();
    }

}

class AppGUI {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button1;

    AppGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new JPanel();
        button1 = new JButton("button");
        frame.add(panel);
        button1.setSize(new Dimension(100, 40));

        panel.add(button1);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: *How can i change size and position of button* - you don't. You let the layout manager determine the size/location of the button based on the rules of the layout manager. So the solution is to use the appropriate [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to achieve your desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, this would work:

```
  AppGUI()
  {
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    button1 = new JButton("button");
    frame.add(panel);
    button1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 140));
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 140));
    button1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 140));

    panel.add(button1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
```

But the proper solution depends on what you want to achieve, i.e. how your frame should look like at the end. In Swing, you do not use specific dimensions but you let layout managers to decide by themselves so your GUI looks properly on different platforms/skins and is properly resizable. GridBagLayout is used more often, at least in applications created by myself.